# Why image is not saved in the server using POST?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, post

I have to save image to the server but image is not saving and other things is saving. I am using this code but not getting the result what I want... I have to save image into this address 
http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/ulpoad/post/imagename

```
- (IBAction)SaveAction:(id)sender

{
    NSString *businessStr = BusinessField.text;
    NSString *addStr = AddressField.text;
    NSString *webStr = websiteField.text;
    NSString *fbStr = facebookField.text;
    NSString *twitStr = twitterField.text;
    NSString *instaStr = instagramField.text;
    NSString *tumbStr = tumblerField.text;
    NSString *pintStr = pinterestField.text;
    NSString *shortStr = shortDescView.text;
    NSString *longStr = longDescView.text;
    NSString *categoryStr = categoridddd.text;
    NSString *subcategoryStr = subcategoryidddd.text;
    NSString *countStr = CountryLabel.text;
    NSString *stateStr = StateLabel.text;
    NSString *cityStr = cityField.text;
    NSString *NameString = personNameField.text;
    NSString *emailString = emailField.text;
    NSString *phoneString = phoneField.text;


    [self randomStringWithLength:8];

    [self randomStringImageWithLength:5];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [parameters setValue:businessStr forKey:@"title"];
    [parameters setValue:cityStr forKey:@"city"];
    [parameters setValue:stateStr forKey:@"state"];
    [parameters setValue:countStr forKey:@"country"];
    [parameters setValue:addStr forKey:@"address"];
    [parameters setValue:userID forKey:@"memberId"];
    [parameters setValue:strName forKey:@"UserName"];
    [parameters setValue:@"0" forKey:@"isfeatured"];
    [parameters setValue:categoryStr forKey:@"prod_name"];
    [parameters setValue:subcategoryStr forKey:@"var_name"];
    [parameters setValue:@"0" forKey:@"package_name"];
    [parameters setValue:@"0" forKey:@"category"];
    [parameters setValue:shortStr forKey:@"shortdesc"];
    [parameters setValue:longStr forKey:@"longdesc"];
    [parameters setValue:@"35" forKey:@"amount"];
    [parameters setValue:@" " forKey:@"catname"];
    [parameters setValue:NameString forKey:@"contactperson"];
    [parameters setValue:phoneString forKey:@"business_phone"];
    [parameters setValue:@" " forKey:@"tags"];
    [parameters setValue:@"365" forKey:@"subs_name"];
    [parameters setValue:@"35" forKey:@"subs_price"];
    [parameters setValue:timeStampStr forKey:@"paydate"];
    [parameters setValue:timeStampStr forKey:@"startdate"];
    [parameters setValue:endDateStr forKey:@"enddate"];
    [parameters setValue:randomString forKey:@"transactionid"];
    [parameters setValue:@"ZWZ3QDEyMw==" forKey:@"api_key"];
    [parameters setValue:@"123456" forKey:@"api_password"];
    [parameters setValue:webStr forKey:@"web_address"];
    [parameters setValue:fbStr forKey:@"fb_address"];
    [parameters setValue:twitStr forKey:@"tw_address"];
    [parameters setValue:instaStr forKey:@"inst_address"];
    [parameters setValue:pintStr forKey:@"pt_address"];
    [parameters setValue:tumbStr forKey:@"tb_address"];

    NSString *boundary = @"------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuM1cE5lMwCy";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/api/addbusiness"];

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    for (NSString *param in parameters) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parameters objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 1.0);

    NSString *FileParamConstant =@"ImageFile";

    if (imageData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the request
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // set URL
    [request setURL:baseUrl];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {

        NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"response : %@",test);

                               NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

                               if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {

                                   NSLog(@"success");
                               }

                           }];
}
```

Please help me . I am trying this from yesterday. Thanks for any help

Comment: first learn basics of iOS. Then move ahead

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)SaveAction:(id)sender
{
    NSString *strServicePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/api/addbusiness"];
                                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strServicePath]];
                                [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
                                [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
                                [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
                                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                                //    NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";
                                NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

                                // set Content-Type in HTTP header
                                NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
                                [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

                                NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                                [parameters setValue:businessStr forKey:@"title"];
                                [parameters setValue:cityStr forKey:@"city"];
                                [parameters setValue:stateStr forKey:@"state"];
                                [parameters setValue:countStr forKey:@"country"];
                                [parameters setValue:addStr forKey:@"address"];
                                [parameters setValue:userID forKey:@"memberId"];
                                [parameters setValue:strName forKey:@"UserName"];
                                [parameters setValue:@"0" forKey:@"isfeatured"];
                                [parameters setValue:categoryStr forKey:@"prod_name"];
                                [parameters setValue:subcategoryStr forKey:@"var_name"];
                                [parameters setValue:@"0" forKey:@"package_name"];
                                [parameters setValue:@"0" forKey:@"category"];
                                [parameters setValue:shortStr forKey:@"shortdesc"];
                                [parameters setValue:longStr forKey:@"longdesc"];
                                [parameters setValue:@"35" forKey:@"amount"];
                                [parameters setValue:@" " forKey:@"catname"];
                                [parameters setValue:NameString forKey:@"contactperson"];
                                [parameters setValue:phoneString forKey:@"business_phone"];
                                [parameters setValue:@" " forKey:@"tags"];
                                [parameters setValue:@"365" forKey:@"subs_name"];
                                [parameters setValue:@"35" forKey:@"subs_price"];
                                [parameters setValue:timeStampStr forKey:@"paydate"];
                                [parameters setValue:timeStampStr forKey:@"startdate"];
                                [parameters setValue:endDateStr forKey:@"enddate"];
                                [parameters setValue:randomString forKey:@"transactionid"];
                                [parameters setValue:@"ZWZ3QDEyMw==" forKey:@"api_key"];
                                [parameters setValue:@"123456" forKey:@"api_password"];
                                [parameters setValue:webStr forKey:@"web_address"];
                                [parameters setValue:fbStr forKey:@"fb_address"];
                                [parameters setValue:twitStr forKey:@"tw_address"];
                                [parameters setValue:instaStr forKey:@"inst_address"];
                                [parameters setValue:pintStr forKey:@"pt_address"];
                                [parameters setValue:tumbStr forKey:@"tb_address"];

                                // post body
                                NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
                                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                                for (NSString *param in parameters) {
                                    NSMutableString *strPart = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self createPartWithKey:param value:[_params objectForKey:param] boundary:boundary encoding:@"8bit" contentType:@"text/plain" contentFilename:@""]];
                                    [body appendData:[strPart dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                                }


                                NSString *strProfileImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_.jpg",@"ImageFile"];
                                if (imageData) {
                                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=%@\r\n", @"profile_pic",strProfileImageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                                    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                                    [body appendData:imageData];
                                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                                }

                                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                                // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
                                [request setHTTPBody:body];

                                // set the content-length
                                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
                                [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

                                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if(data != nil)
        {
            [HUD hideAnimated:YES];
            NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
            NSInteger code = [httpResponse statusCode];
            NSLog(@"Status Code: %ld", (long)code);
            if (code == 200) {
                NSError *error;
                id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            }
        }
        });
}
```